# Java NDK и серийные порты: termios.h работает с Android 5.0, как заставить его работать на 4.2?

Tags: android, android-ndk, serial

Я пытался работать через android-serial-api, jssc с серийным портом в Android, и в любом случае имею проблему:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "tcgetattr" referenced by "libjssc.so"...
```

Я не спец с С++, и погуглил про tcgetattr. Вот, что нашёл:

tcgetattr() : получить параметры, связанные с объектом, на который ссылается fd, и сохранить их в структуре termios, на которую ссылается termios_p. Эта функция может быть запущена из фонового процесса; однако, атрибуты терминала могут в дальнейшем изменяться основным процессом.

tcsetattr(): меняет параметры, связанные с терминалом (если требуется поддержка используемого оборудования, которая недоступна), и параметры структуры termios, связанной с termios_p. Для того, чтобы изменения вступили в силу, необходимо указать optional_actions:

То есть это задаёт настройки com-порта, и необходимы для работы. При этом termios.h присутствует во всех версиях Android, в том числе в интересующей мне 4.2.2 (c:\AndroidSdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-17\arch-arm\usr\include\termios.h), и компилируется без проблем.

Помогите разобраться, что не так в версиях до 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

Там в API 21 много чего в плане NDK поменяли.

.so'шки собранные под 21 могут просто не работать на устройстве с API 19. Попробуйте собрать проект под API 19.

Comment: то есть targetSDK сделать 19?

Comment: @Eugene да, в Android.mk, если вы его используете.

Comment: У меня gradle-experimental. Я в app.xml, model.adroid.ndk.platformVersion поставил "= 17". Там же надо? Это ничего не поменяло.

Comment: @Eugene да, вероятно там. Я просто последний раз с NDK работал, когда ещё Студии не было. Тогда только с помщью Android.mk можно было это делать. А вы старые сгенерированные .so файлы удалили перед этим?